# passing member function const and non-const overload to std::function

Tags: c++, overloading, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, std-function

I was trying to get "more fluent" with function pointer manipulation and I've got an issue with passing a member function to `std::function` when there are two overload: const and non-const. Based on other stackoverflow posts, I eventually succeeded, using `static_cast` but it's all but readable.
Here is a dummy working example. The core of the issue is wrapping two member-function overloads (const and non-const):

```cpp
#include <functional>

struct dummy {
    int val = 42;
    int get() const { return val; }
    int& get() { return val; }
};

int main() {
    dummy obj;
    // std::function<int& (dummy &)> f = &dummy::get;
    // std::function<int (dummy const &)> f = &dummy::get;
    std::function<int&(dummy&)> f = static_cast<int& (dummy::*)()>(&dummy::get);
    std::function<int(dummy const&)> fc =
        static_cast<int (dummy::*)() const>(&dummy::get);

    // just to check that it works as expected
    f(obj) = 36;
    return fc(obj); // ok retrives 36
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/nEnrq5ann)
Is there a simpler syntax?

Comment: Another option is not overloading `get` methods that way.

Comment: `auto f = [&obj]() -> int& { return obj.get(); };` and `auto fc = [&obj = std::as_const(obj)]() { return obj.get(); };`

Comment: With that said, getters are not always a good idea. And using classes or structures as simple containers of variables might not always be the best design choice.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As the struct name implied, it was just a dummy working example. The core of the issue is wrapping two overloads of a member function (const and non-const)

Answer (score 3):

[Addresses of overload set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address) cannot be reduced for `std::function`, but you can write helpers to simplify the "cast":

```
template <typename Ret, typename C, typename...Ts>
auto overload(Ret(C::*m)(Ts...)) { return m; }

template <typename Ret, typename C, typename...Ts>
auto const_overload(Ret(C::*m)(Ts...) const) { return m; }
```

then

```
std::function<int& (dummy &)> f = overload(&dummy::get);
std::function<int (dummy const &)> fc = const_overload(&dummy::get);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8vP4TMGh4)

Those helpers won't help to differentiate `void C::foo(int)`/`void C::foo(float)` though and would requires other helpers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda expression:

```
std::function<int&(dummy&)> f = [](dummy& d) -> int& { return d.get(); };    
std::function<int(dummy const&)> fc = [](const dummy& d) { return d.get(); };
```

I didn't manage to convince gcc to accept the first line without explicitly specifiying `int&` return type tough.

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/P1h3Gf5q8)

If you want to actaully stay with function pointers, I am not aware of something "simpler". Imho the `static_cast` is very clear about what is going on. It is possible to use type aliases to make it less verbose, but it will most certainly also be less readable.